# I need help organizing my legend labels[matplotlib] in rows instead of columns

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, legend

Let's say I have 22 plots in one figure and I want to display their legends as rows and not columns... ncols aranges the labels in columns, like if i have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7....,22 as labels it displays as

1  11

2  12

3  13

...

10 22

instead of

1  2

3  4

5  6

....

21 22

[this is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJdLq.png)

[this is what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kupY.png)

[the code i have rn looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goi9A.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  In particular, the section "Help others reproduce the problem".

Comment: Please never put the code as image, always as text.